# Compiz: how to combine scale and expo? (like in Unity with Mutter)

Tags: 10.10, unity, 11.04, compiz

Unity in Ubuntu 10.10 has a nice effect when showing the four workspaces. The Windows on each Workspace are shown side by side.

The Compiz Version of Unity only uses Expo to show the workspaces, but the windows stays as they are. Is it possible to combine Expo and Scale to get the same effekt like in Unity 10.10? Or will the new Unity become this effect someday?

**Related information on [launchpad](http://launchpad.net):**
[Bug #712072](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/712072): Combine expo and scale plugins in Unity
[Question #14330](https://answers.launchpad.net/unity/+question/143300): Workspace switcher behaviour
[Bug #703804](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/703804): Integration issues with expo plugin and Unity shell

Comment: Burli, I think Sam - Canonical's official Compiz dev :) - answered your question quite nicely. If you think that too, please mark the question as answered!

Answer (score 7):

Lots of people clicking a button doesn't necessarily mean a feature will be implemented :) someone has to find the time to implement the feature.

That being said, I'm going to find a way to combine the two, but we have more important things to focus on right now (stability etc)

Comment: No problem, I know that there are more important things. I want you just to know that there are people out there who want this feature back :). If this feature comes in 11.10 oder 12.04 it's ok

Comment: I did not mean that clicking will necessarily lead to an implementation, just that if the user has the feeling that he is affected by this "bug" thats where he should click. (Instead of writing "I want this too" or similar). Bugs with many users affected are supposed to get more developer attention...

Comment: Just reread my post: I did not mean to come off so rude, sorry.
Stability is obviously more important, and I am glad to hear that this feature is planed in the future.

Comment: Looking forward to this functionality!

Comment: Due to limitations on how Xorg handles input doing this will likely require either outright merging the two plugins in to one or providing the expo plugin some way to know where the scale plugin has moved things. Either one of those is, honestly, going to be a pain.

Answer (score 2):

I searched for this a while ago, and according to all the forum discussion it is not possible with compiz currently.

I posted a bug report based on your question asking for this feature:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/712072

Please click "Does this Bug affect you too?" if you would like this implemented

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could try **Cinnamon**: [Version 1.4](http://cinnamon.linuxmint.com/?p=182) now has this feature. Install [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~gwendal-lebihan-dev/+archive/cinnamon-stable), run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install cinnamon`. Log out and before logging in again choose Cinnamon instead of Unity.

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature called [Spread](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/03/new-unity-spread-design-for-ubuntu-1210.html) which will bring this to Unity, but it is unlikely that it will be landed in the Compiz version, seeing as Unity is returning to being a Qt application.

It will probably come in Ubuntu 14.04 (approximately), as part of [Unity Next](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UnityNextSpec).